# Nautilus exits unexpectedly

Tags: nautilus

If I **unmount a drive** using nautilus the **nautilus-window closes** - I don't know why. 
I think it's a bug, or is there a way to change this useless behaviour of the default gnome-file-manager.

Comment: It closes if you unmount the drive while you are viewing the contents of the drive you are unmounting? Switch to a different drive, or your home folder, first.

Comment: Thank you, dobey, for your answer. I just wanted to add that it happens not allways. It's repeatable that nautilus exits only if the viewed mounted drive will be unmounted. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If you are looking at the drive you're about to unmount, the window (or tab) will go away, as the drive is no longer there once you unmount it. Yes, it is a bit disconcerting at first.